# No written contract. Do I have to pay undisclosed early termination fee?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, california, business

A credit card payment processing company agent approached my business and offered to try out their service for free for a month as a trial. 
However, I decided not to use it after this one month trial, and request to cancel. 
Now they have already charged $840 as cancellation fee and PoS deprecation fee. Since there was no contract, I don't agree to pay these fees. **Do I really have to pay them?**

Comment: It sounds steep, to be sure, but what did your contract say?

Comment: @PatW. There was no written contract. Verbally they promised free trial(no early termination fee was mentioned).

Comment: I'd be shocked if there's not an agreement somewhere...processing firms generally don't dole out services on the strength of a conversation.

Answer (score 3):

A contract need not be written to be valid and enforceable.  However, if there is no written contract, then in a dispute the burden of proving (via a preponderance of evidence) a contractual obligation falls on the party asserting it.  In the scenario you describe it *sounds* like that would be impossible for the processing company.